# Canvas Drawing From List Objects Random non drawing

Tags: java, android, game-development

When I try to draw game items that are in a list.  Some don't draw.
I have noticed that the issue occurs when objects that are the same are the ones casing teh issue. Canvas will draw one of them, but skip the rest.  I have attached a short video that shows the problem (19 seconds).
http://www.nexxiom.com/temp/qq-screen1.mp4

I should mention that this issue does not occur anywhere else such as in the inventory screens.

Here is the code for my BattleResultDialog:

```
Paint fadePaint;
int scrollMarginTop;
int scrollPaddingTop;
int frameCount;

int questTextSize, completeTextSize;

boolean battleWin;

ArrayList<GameItem>rewards;

public BattleResultDialog(boolean battleComplete, Enemy enemyObject) {
    super(540,1080,1080,2160);
    rewards = enemyObject.rewardsList;
    scrollMarginTop = scaling.DrawY(100);
    scrollPaddingTop = scaling.DrawY(100);

    fadePaint = new Paint();
    fadePaint.setARGB(0,0,0,0);

    questTextSize = 0;

    if(MainActivity.playerData.hp > 0 && battleComplete){
        battleWin = true;
        int count = 0;

        for (GameItem g: rewards) {
                g.updateXY(((160*count)),1080);
                Log.d("ITEMTYPE:",g.itemType+":: X:"+g.x+": y:"+g.y);
            count++;
        }
        SocketManager.myConsumableList.addAll(rewards);
        MainActivity.playerData.xp += SocketManager.Enemylist.get(MainActivity.playerData.currentEnemyIndex).xpReward;
        MainActivity.playerData.currentEnemyIndex = 0;
        mapSelectIcon = new MapSelectIcon(0,0,0,0,false,1,MainActivity.playerData.currentEnemyIndex);
        SocketManager.Enemylist.get(MainActivity.playerData.currentEnemyIndex).isDead = true;
        SocketManager.Enemylist.remove(enemyObject);

        for (Enemy e:SocketManager.Enemylist) {
            e.ResetMapIcons();
        }

        MainActivity.playerData.TallyLVL();


    }

}






public void update() {
    super.update();
    frameCount++;


    if(MainActivity.playerData.justUpgradedLVL){
        //run an level up animation
        if(frameCount >30){
            MainActivity.playerData.justUpgradedLVL = false;
        }

    }

    if(battleWin){
        for (GameItem g:rewards) {
            g.update();
        }
    }

    if(frameCount >30 && frameCount < 60){
        //"QUEST" POP IN
        questTextSize = questTextSize + 4;

    }
    if(frameCount >45 && frameCount < 75){
        //"COMPLETE" POP IN
        completeTextSize = completeTextSize + 4;

    }



    if(fadePaint.getAlpha() <= 245){
        fadePaint.setAlpha(fadePaint.getAlpha()+9);
    }else{
        fadePaint.setAlpha(255);

    }








}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(Globals.SplashBG,0,0,fadePaint); //zindex 0

   // canvas.drawBitmap(BigScroll,super.rect.left,super.rect.top+scrollMarginTop,fadePaint);

        canvas.drawText("BATTLE", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(100) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, questTextSize, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
        canvas.drawText("BATTLE", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(100) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, questTextSize, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));
        canvas.drawText("RESULTS", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(300) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, completeTextSize, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
        canvas.drawText("RESULTS", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(300) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, completeTextSize, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));

        if(battleWin){

            canvas.drawText("YALL WON", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(700) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, completeTextSize, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
            canvas.drawText("YALL WON", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(700) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, completeTextSize, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));

            //Show the reward Items
            canvas.drawText("numRewards"+rewards.size(), super.rect.centerX(), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(1400), TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, 40, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
            canvas.drawText("numRewards"+rewards.size(), super.rect.centerX(), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(1400), TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, 40, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));

                for (GameItem g:rewards) {
                    g.draw(canvas);
                }



        }else{

            canvas.drawText("YALL DIED", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(700) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, completeTextSize, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
            canvas.drawText("YALL DIED", super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(700) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, completeTextSize, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));


        }
   // canvas.drawText("numRewards "+this.rewards.size(), super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(1400) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.black, 60, 0, 6, R.font.grobold,255));
   // canvas.drawText("numRewards "+this.rewards.size(), super.rect.left + (super.rect.width() / 2), super.rect.top + scaling.DrawY(1400) + scrollPaddingTop + scrollMarginTop, TextGen.getFont(android.R.color.white, 60, 0, 0, R.font.grobold,255));

    if(MainActivity.playerData.justUpgradedLVL){
        //run an level up animation


    }




}


    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){



   //checkPointNextBTN.onTouchEvent(e);

        float posX = e.getX();
        float posY = e.getY();

        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                if (posX >= super.rect.left && posX <= super.rect.right && posY >= super.rect.top && posY <= super.rect.bottom) {

                   // if()
                        if(battleWin){

                            MainActivity.SaveDataConsumableList(Globals.context);
                            MainActivity.SaveData(Globals.context);
                            MainActivity.GLOBALS.GSM = new GameStateManager(0); //Scanner

                        }else{
                            MainActivity.SaveDataConsumableList(Globals.context);
                            MainActivity.SaveData(Globals.context);
                            MainActivity.GLOBALS.GSM = new GameStateManager(3); //Character Screen
                        }


                        return;


                  



                }


            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            }
            break;


        }

    }



}
```

LOGCAT

ITEMTYPE:      4:: X:-80: y:1000

ITEMTYPE:      2:: X:80: y:1000

ITEMTYPE:      4:: X:240: y:1000

ITEMTYPE:      3:: X:400: y:1000

ITEMTYPE:      4:: X:560: y:1000

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it.

I created new objects instead of referencing objects in my object source list.

so instead of something like this:

gameItem = (GameItem)sourceList.get(randomSourceIndex).get(randomItemIndex);

I'm now instantiating new Objects that are strongly TYPED:

```
        HpItem hpItem = new HpItem(0,0,160,160,0);
        FluxItem fluxItem = new FluxItem(0,0,160,160,0);
        RemoteAccessItem remoteAccessItem = new RemoteAccessItem(0,0,160,160,0);
```

Then I copy the last field (qty) to the corresponding item by type.. this probably doesnt make any sense to you without seeing more code.  But what I think was happening is that when I am drawing out the positions of the reward items,  items of the same index from the source list were just getting stacked on top of each other. because they all referenced the same object from the sourcelist.  Anyway, I spent all day trying to figure this out and read alot of articles and documentation on copying objects and cloning and such.  But I guess it just came down to using the NEW keyword and recreating the objects... but I'm still unclear about it all. There is no cloning or deep copying.. So isnt the reference still in tact? I dont know but,  creating new objects fixed it. This method is called when the enemies are generated on startup.
I didnt include it in my OP because I didnt know the issue needed to be tracked back this far.  Cheers

The full method

```
  public static ArrayList<GameItem> GenerateGameItemsRandom() {

    int numRewards = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 5);

    //create a temp master source list
    ArrayList<GameItem> returnItem = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    sourceList.add(SocketManager.ConsumableSourceList);
    //sourceList.add(SocketManager.WeaponSourceList);
    GameItem gameItem;

    int randomSourceIndex;
    int randomItemIndex;
    for(int i=0;i<numRewards;i++){

        randomSourceIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sourceList.size());
        randomItemIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, sourceList.get(randomSourceIndex).size());

        gameItem = (GameItem)sourceList.get(randomSourceIndex).get(randomItemIndex);
        HpItem hpItem = new HpItem(0,0,160,160,0);
        FluxItem fluxItem = new FluxItem(0,0,160,160,0);
        RemoteAccessItem remoteAccessItem = new RemoteAccessItem(0,0,160,160,0);


        switch (randomSourceIndex) {

            case 0: //consumable

                switch(gameItem.itemType){

                    case 2:
                        HpItem item_hp = (HpItem)gameItem;
                        hpItem.qty = item_hp.qty;
                        returnItem.add(hpItem);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        FluxItem item_flux = (FluxItem)gameItem;
                        fluxItem.qty = item_flux.qty;
                        returnItem.add(fluxItem);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        RemoteAccessItem item_ra = (RemoteAccessItem) gameItem;
                        remoteAccessItem.qty = item_ra.qty;
                        returnItem.add(item_ra);
                        break;

                }


                break;

        }

    }



    return returnItem;

}
```